# Spring Boot MultipartFile always has value of null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload

So I'm making a RESTful API backend for a JavaScript frontend and want to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage. I have this function to handle the file upload:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@ModelAttribute("file") FileDTO fileDTO) {
        FunctionResponse uploadResponse = cloudStorage.uploadObject(fileDTO.getFile());
        if (uploadResponse.successful()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(uploadResponse.getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(uploadResponse.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

My fileDTO class looks like this:

```
public class FileDTO implements Serializable {

    private MultipartFile file;

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

However whenever I try and access the MultipartFile it always throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
I have tried various SO answers from threads with similar problems but none have worked so far.

I have `multipart.enabled=true` in my application.properties.

Any help would be appreciated and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: (1) What if you change `@ModelAttribute("file")` with `@ModelAttribute` (remove "file") ? (2) In the frontend, is "file" the identifier of the submitted file ?

Comment: @g.momo Removing ("file") still gives the NullPointerException and yes file is the identifier of the submitted file. It is passed in the body of the request as form-data

Comment: Now I see, you needed a setter `setFile(Multipartfile file)` in your FileDto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `multipart/form-data` request arrives, the data must be obtained by using `@RequestParam`, not `@ModelAttribute` + if the value you need of the request is a file, then, it should be deserialized into a  `MultipartFile` object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file) {
    // your handle ...
}
```